# Subtractive Categories

Tags: category-theory, relations

I found two different definitions of 'subtractive category' and I am wondering if they are the same or what.

1) A category is subtractive if it is pointed, regular and for every object $X$ of the category, the morphism $p_X$ is a regular epimorphism

2) A category is subtractive if it is pointed, regular and for every object $X$ of the category, every reflexive left puctual relation on $X$ is also right-punctual.

Explanation: the morphism $p_X$ is the following composite:
$$p_X= \binom{1_x}{0}\circ\delta_X:D(X)\to X$$

where $(D(X),\delta_X)$ is the kernel of the codiagonal morphism $\nabla_X=\binom{1_X}{1_X}:X+X\to X$ and $\binom{1_X}{0}:X+X\to X$ the factorization through $X+X$ of the pair of morphisms $\{1_X,0\}$.

Given a reflexive relation $r:R\to X$ on $X$, with $r=(r_1,r_2)$, being left puctual means that there exists a morphism $s:X\to R$ such that $r_1s=1_X, r_2s=0$. Being right-puntual means that there is a morphism $t:X\to R$ such that $r_2t=1_x$ and $r_1t=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the two definitions are equivalent (assuming the category has coproducts).

Assume first that 1) is true. Given a left punctual reflexive relation $r=(r_1,r_2)$, then the universal property of the coproduct yields a map $\binom{\delta}{s}:X+X\to R$ (where $\delta$ is the arrow $X\to R$ given by the reflexivity, and one can check that
$$r_1\binom{\delta}{s}=\binom{r_1\delta}{r_1s}=\binom{1_X}{1_X}=\nabla_X$$
and
$$r_2\binom{\delta}{s}=\binom{r_2\delta}{r_2s}=\binom{1_X}{0}.$$
The first equation implies that $\binom{\delta}{s}$ must restrict to a map $\theta:D(X)\to Ker(r_1)$ between the kernels. Then
$$r_2\circ  \ker(r_1) \circ \theta=r_2\binom{\delta}{s}\delta_X=\binom{1_X}{0}\delta_X=p_X$$
is a regular epimorphism, and thus $r_2\circ \ker(r_1)$ is also a regular epimorphism. But it is also a monomorphism: indeed, for any arrows $u,v$ one has
$$r_1\circ \ker(r_1)\circ u=0=r_1\circ \ker(r_1)\circ v,$$
so if
$$r_2\circ \ker(r_1)\circ u=r_2\circ \ker(r_1)\circ v,$$
one must have $\ker(r_1)\circ u=\ker(r_1)\circ v$ and thus $u=v$. Thus $r_2\circ \ker(r_1)$ is an isomorphism, and we can assume WLOG that is actually equal to $1_X$, which shows that $r$ is right punctual.

Now assume that 2) is true. Consider the image factorization $rp$ of the canonical arrow
$$\left(\binom{1_X}{1_X},\binom{1_X}{10}\right):X+X\to X\times X.$$
Then $r$ is a monomorphism $R\to X\times X$, thus a relation; and it is reflexive and left punctual (thanks to the coproduct injections $i_1$ and $i_2$ composed with $p$), hence also right punctual. Then the arrow $t$ such that $r_1t=0$ and $r_2t=1_X$ must factor through $\ker(r_1)$, which means that $r_2\circ \ker(r_1)$ is a split epimorphism; since it is also a mono, it is an isomorphism, and then the factorization of $t$ through $Ker(r_1)$ must also be an isomorphism, so we can assume WLOG that $t=\ker(r_1)$. Now the identity $r_1p=\nabla_X$ gives once again a restriction $\theta$ of $p$ to the kernels. Moreover, one can prove that the commutative square $p\delta_X=\ker(r_1)\theta$ is actually a pullback, thus $\theta$ is a regular epimorphism. Thus
$$p_X=\binom{1_X}{0}\delta_X=r_2 p\delta_X=r_2\ker(r_1)\theta=\theta$$
is a regular epimorphism.

Comment: Could you please explain me the WLOG part? Why can I assume wlog that $r_2\circ \operatorname{ker}(r_1)$, being an iso, is equal to the identity on $X$?

Comment: @bateman Kernels are only defined up to isomorphism, so if $\alpha$ is an isomorphism, $\ker(r_1)\circ \alpha$ is also a kernel of $r_1$. In particular, if you take $\alpha$ to be the inverse of $r_2\circ \ker(r_1)$, then $\ker(r_1)\circ \alpha$ is a kernel of $r_1$ and a section of $r_2$.

Comment: Just a last question: you say regular epi+mono---> iso. Is this a general fact, or should I require something on the category?

Comment: It's a general fact: a regular epi $p:B\to C$ is by definition the coequalizer of two arrows $u,v:A\to B$, but if is also a mono then $u=v$. Then $1_B$ coequalizes $u$ and $v$, and thus the universal property of $p$ implies that $p$ must be a split mono. But it must also be an epi (because otherwise you can't have uniqueness in the universal property), hence it is an iso. Alternatively, any regular epi is strong, and strong epi+mono=iso.

Comment: I realized I didn't understand this: $r_2\circ\ker(r_1)\circ\theta$ is a regular epi implies $r_2\circ\ker(r_1)$ is a regular epi too. What are you using to observe that? If $\theta$ is epi, I can prove, but I can't prove that $\theta is epi...

Comment: Why would you need that $\theta$ is an epi? In any category, if $g\circ f$ is a strong epi then $g$ is a strong epi, and in a regular category the same is true for regular epimorphisms since they coincide with the strong ones.